# Display IDataErrorInfo Error in Textblock instead of Tooltip

Tags: c#, wpf, idataerrorinfo, validation

I've seen lots of examples of how to display an error in a tooltip of a textbox. Can someone give me an example of how to display an error in a separate TextBlock instead of in a tooltip of the TextBox?

I'm particularly interested in knowing how to do this if the textbox and textblock are in different views. The view with the textblock has access to the data that has IDataErrorInfo implemented on it though.

Comment: It's a simple transfer, if you have seen how it's done with a tooltip you should know how to get a validation error, from there it should be trivial to get it displayed somewhere else than the tooltip.

Comment: Again, the rub is that they are in different views, so I don't have access to the original TextBox. So I can't point to the element name. If it's so simple, answer the question with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing is adding a property that I set with the Error text. Anytime my Name property is updated, if it has an error, I update the NameError property. I was then able to bind to that property. It seems a little dirty but it did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

you wrote

> The view with the textblock has access to the data that has
>   IDataErrorInfo implemented on it though.

so one way could be to just bind the textblock to the same property like your textbox do. then create a validationtemplate for your textblock wich cover the whole textblock.

EDIT: maybe something like this?

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="MyAdornedElement" />  
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MyAdornedElement,Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

you have to add this to the textblock style of course

Comment: I'm not quite following. How is this linking to my data? So do I have to bind the AdornedElementPlaceholder to the data so that it gets the errors?